# Next-auth - unable to redirect to specific url after successful login/logout (keycloak provider)

Tags: next.js, keycloak, next-auth

I have a two basic next apps that uses next-auth for its authentication along with **keycloak** provider.

i've been trying to use the feature of SSO (single sign on) that keyckoak provides, so i have a website running on **http://localhost:3000/** and another one on **http://localhost:3001/**, and everytime i try to login using the second app, it redirects me to localhost 3000, not localhost 3001, which is a weird behavior, let me show you some code.

**api/auth/[...nextauth].ts**

(note: i'm using same realm and clientId for both apps)

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import KeycloackProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";

export default NextAuth({
  debug: true,
  providers: [
    KeycloackProvider({
      clientId: "react-client-1",
      clientSecret: "react-auth",
      issuer: "http://localhost:8080/realms/react-auth",
enter image description here    }),
  ],
});
```

**Function to sign in**

here, the callbackUrl just doesn't work, no matter what i put there, it's just not going to redirect me to that url

```
const handleKeycloackSignIn = (): void => {
    signIn("keycloak", {
      callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3001/",
    });
  };
```

**next-auth cookies for redirecting on** **localhost:3001**

[photo #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnYvy.jpg)

**Keycloack config**

[photo #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaUFY.png)

What could be the reason for always redirecting to localhost:3000 ? is it some next-auth config that i'm missing or, maybe is related to keycloak ?

How can i redirect to wherever i want after a successful login/logout

I've tried hardcore google search around this topic, nothing really related to my specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some variables that next-auth need to your .env file, something like this.

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=PRUEBA
```

this provides the url to redirect and a secret to your jwt token